# c9.io How to Connect to a Microsoft SQL Database using PDO in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, c9.io

I'm using c9.io and I am trying to access a Microsoft SQL database using PDO, but I'm getting the error message "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'".
From what I've found, I need to add the php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll to my php directory and then add it to my php.ini file. however I have not been able to find a way to move the dll into the directory where the rest of the php .dll's are stored. Is there an easy way for me to move this dll into place and get this working?
Or is there a different way that I should be doing this?

c9.io is running ubuntu (if that helps).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean you can't move it? You should just be able to copy and paste it. Also, is the c9.io tag relevant? Isn't it just a web-based text editor or is it what's actually running your PHP?

Comment: This seems like a tech support question, not a stack O question...

Comment: Chris - c9.io is a web-based development environment. and the directory where php is installed is not within my workspace, so I have to use the command-line to manipulate it.

Comment: I could be wrong, but does c9.io actually run on Windows? I figured it was just a Linux thing.

Comment: beattyac - Well, I thought someone might be able to help or give advice through stackOverFlow, so I thought it was worth a try.

Comment: Chris- my initial post says it is running on ubuntu. I access it via web-browser. If you don't know what c9.io is you should probably look it up.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I have looked it up. I was just confused by the fact you were trying to install Windows DLLs on it.

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not use DLLs. You probably want to install the Linux Microsoft SQL PDO driver ([DBLIB](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)) by running this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sybase
```

Comment: Thank you, however this did not solve the problem. after installing, I am  still missing the required driver.